# What counts as turf?

Tags: splatoon

What should I be aiming to hit to increase my team's final percentage? I read that walls don't count, but what about the halfpipes? How can I tell if a surface counts or not?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does paint on the walls count?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/317269/does-paint-on-the-walls-count)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is everything that is visible in the top-down view. So halfpipes do count, as well as slopes. I do not know exactly how much area 1 turf (as a point) is.