# Does paint on the walls count?

Tags: splatoon-2

In turf war, does paint on the walls (vertical planes) count, or does only the paint visible from the bird eye (horizontal planes) view count in the final scores?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What counts as turf?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/223977/what-counts-as-turf)

Comment: If we remove the [tag:splatoon] tag, this technically wouldn't be a duplicate.  I'm guessing (based off when this was asked) is more so about Splatoon 2.  Not sure why it has both tags.  It should only be one or the other.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The only paint that matters is horizontal coverage. Painting the walls may increase your team's maneuverability, but it won't increase your score in Turf War.

Comment: For reference, this applies to both Splatoon 1 and 2

Comment: Inking walls also does not increase your special gauge.

Comment: Relevent VGCats (I will admit to doing this exact thing when I started, though maybe not with a roller): http://www.vgcats.com/comics/?strip_id=365

Comment: What about mobile objects like drawbridges? Tops of trees?

Comment: @Random832 I thinkthe best way to check is to see if your special gauge or point counter go up as you paint them. I don't know exactly how reliable it is, but it should at least give some indication as to whether it counts.